# How can I exclude certain parameters from Rails-generated links by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

We use Rails' `caches_action` method along with Redis to implement caching of common pages. 
It's a very dynamic site, so pages with differing URL params must remain distinct in the cache (e.g. `?page=1` vs `?page=2`). But as long as the URLs match, the content can be cached and served to multiple visitors.

Since a very high portion of our traffic comes from Adwords ads, many of our users were arriving at our pages with a [gclid](http://www.wordstream.com/gclid) param in the URL, which rendered the caching useless. I worked around this by excluding the gclid from the cache path used to identify unique URLs:

```
caches_action :search,
              :expires_in => 10.minutes,
              :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params.except('gclid') }
```

This worked great for a while, until I realized that our Analytics data was off because the HTML we were caching included internal links with the gclid param from previous visits.

So the solution to this is pretty straightforward- every time I generate a link I need to manually exclude `gclid`, like:

```
link_to 'some page', params.except('gclid')
```

My question is: is there any way to automatically exclude `gclid` from all generated links? It would be really handy to not have to do this manually throughout the site.

Comment: Maybe monkey-patching `link_to` method by adding this line of yours.

Comment: Yes, I thought about patching link_to. But I would also have to patch url_for as well, and potentially a few other similar methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Turns out that `link_to` ends up calling `url_for` anyway, so that seems the best place to hook it in.

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    module UrlFor
      alias :original_url_for :url_for
      def url_for(options = {})
        options = options.except(:gclid) if options.kind_of? Hash
        original_url_for options
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282219/93995) by @jdc helper me get there, as did @MurifoX's comment.